# How to replace all / with - from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string field `01/01/1986` and I am using replace method to replace all occurrence of `/` with `-`

```
var test= '01/01/1986';
test.replace('//g','-')
```

but it does't give desire result. Any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have a couple issues: don't put the regex in quotes. That turns it into a string instead of a regex and looks for that literal string. Then use `\/` to escape the `/`:

```js
var test= '01/01/1986';
console.log(test.replace(/\//g,'-'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way is to use split and join.

```js
var test= '01/01/1986';
var result = test.split('/').join('-');

console.log(result);
```

Note too that you need to save the result. The original string itself will never be modified.